# Custom Wizard (C/C++) VS10

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, wizard

i'm trying to create a template for a project (GTK+), where I don't want to have to include always the header-paths. As far as I understand the only possibility to do that in C is to create a custom wizard.

I already created one, and added "Additional Libraries" (in the function AddConfig()). But I can't seem to find how to add VC++ Directories. I guess I could try to add the header-files directly in the project, but I'd rather just "link" to them.

Thanks.

Comment: Google "project property sheets".  First hit is good, switch to VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Such tasks can be solved much easier by means of custom property sheets. A property sheet, once configured and saved, can be added to any C++ project by two mouse clicks in the property manager.

Comment: Thank you. I needed a little time to figure stuff out, but now it works like a charm :)